# Why Are Highchart JS Files Not Validated?

Tags: javascript

I've recently validated all of my HTML and CSS files on my website and now I'm looking into validating JS files. The problem is, there are thousands of errors in the provided Highcharts JS files. My question is, should I bother validating them? Is there a reason that these aren't validated?

Thanks,

William

Comment: How are you validating said code? Also why are you validating it? Validating against what? ES3? ES2016? ES2308? jQueryLoDashHypeOfTheDayStandard? Unit tests?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I am validating it using JSLint. I just wanted to validate the files so that the code was valid just like the HTML and CSS files on my website.

Comment: jslint is a set of highly opinionated checks. It's not even near the same to validating html and css against *the standards*.

Comment: Right, so should I link you to the relevant CSS files and see if they're ok or should I ignore those errors all together?